# iTemplate what is it and place where i can get GOOD example in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

HI ,

I am currently trying to learn more about custom controls and how to use them etc. i have come across **iTemplate** interface and was hoping that someone could better explain its use and point me toward a good example implementation. From what i have found it allows you to change how an asp.net control will display items. ive tried searching code project etc for a good example but none explain it well. Id ideally like a very basic example and a more complex one.

thanks
Niall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ITemplate: Defines the behavior for populating a templated ASP.NET server control with child controls. The child controls represent the inline templates defined on the page. (taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.itemplate.aspx)).

Take a look at these great tutorials: [Developing Custom ASP.NET Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt27tfhy.aspx) or [Templated Server Control Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178657.aspx).

Comment: thanks for that examples are good.